# Deploy Angular image files from assets folder in Spring MVC webapp folder

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc

I deployed my Angular (4) Project in the Spring MVC Project. The Java Web Project is able to work with the Angular Project however the External Stylesheets and the Images files are not being recognized.
I have placed the mage Files in the **src/assets/image/..** folder of the Angular Project.
I have also provided the assets folder info in the .angular-cli.json file

```
 "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Note: The Angular Project is Deployed into the **webapp** folder of the Spring MVC Maven Project

Now, how can I use the image files in the Angular Components so that it won't break when I deploy in the Spring MVC Project?

Comment: So the images are being copied properly on build? What path are you using to access them?

Comment: The Angular app is deployed under "webapp/angular" folder of the Web Project. So the image files are located under the "webapp/angular/assets/image/...." location.

Comment: What path are you using in your components? `/assets/image/...`? Do you have your basehref set to `/`?

Comment: /assets/image/some_image.png and bashref = "."

Comment: can you try changing the basehref to `/`

Comment: I did nothing works... cause initially while developing application in the angular, the images would refer to the "/assets/image/.." directory. but once they are deployed they will refer to the "Web Context Root" and then the location where the Angular is deployed. I am getting -- GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/header 404 () error message

Comment: you could change your basehref to `/webapp/angular/` in your build command `ng build --base-href=/webapp/angular/`

Comment: It worked Finally. I had to put the Web Project name before the Angular Project Folder and then I had to update the index.html deployed in the project and prefix the address of the inline.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js etc with the directory information provided in the ng build command. eg: ng build --base-href=/Web_Project_Name/angular/

Comment: Note, there is also a `--deploy-url ` property you can add to your build command (or in angular-cli.json) that will append the url to your bundle files in index.html (ie `--deploy-url=/Web_Project_Name/angular`)